# Trouble referencing Facebook library in app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android) to use the Facebook API in my app.  I've pull the library from the git repo and now I'm trying to reference it in my app.  However, I can't seem to select the library.  Does it have to be located in a certain directory relative to my project?  Right now, my project and the library are at the same directory level.

[image: ss]

Comment: Did you ensure the facebook library is marked as a Library Project in its properties.

Comment: I'm not sure where to do this. I don't see a reference to it on the page I linked.

Comment: In the facebook project properties, click `Is Library`

Comment: Also make sure that the facebook library project is open and in your workspace. If its a closed project, you can't reference it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the tutorial you gave, you first need to create a project from the source, of the facebook library downloaded from git and only then to add it as library, otherwise it won't work.